# Dynamically Load an Actor if it's there

Tags: scala, akka, scala-reflect

I have the following code

```
lazy val restEndpoint = context.actorOf(Props[RestEndpoint], "RestEndpoint")
```

However, I want to dynamically load the actor if it's there for a few reasons:

1. It may not be on the classpath, so I would have to ask the class loader if it's there.
2. Even if it's on the classpath, I may not want to load it for configuration reasons.
3. RestEndpoint is in a different JAR file that already has dependencies on this JAR file, so I can't have circular dependencies.

Is there some 'easy' way to do this reflectively? Please don't point me at the documentation on reflection in Scala, because there is nothing easy there. If there is a Scala Reflection for Dummies discussion I would appreciate looking at that.

A working example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really glad we have a Typesafe support contract. Here is the solution we came up with. I have tested the code, and it works. Note: reflection was not necessary, which made me very happy.

```
def actorRefForName(className: String) = try {
  val actorClass = Class.forName(className)
  Some(context.actorOf(Props(actorClass), actorClass.getSimpleName))
} catch {
  case classNotFoundException: ClassNotFoundException =>
  log.info(s"class $className not found. This actor will not be used")
  None
}

. . .

lazy val kinesisProducer =
  actorRefForName("com._3tierlogic.KinesisManager.producer.KinesisProducer")

. . .

def receive = {

  case Start =>

    kinesisProducer match {
      case Some(kinesisProducerRef) =>
        log.info("Starting " + kinesisProducerRef.path.name)
        kinesisProducerRef ! Start
      case None =>
        log.info("There is no Kinesis Producer actor to start.")
    }

  case Started =>

    // foreach is a little confusing when there is only Some or None, but
    // basically we can only use our actorRef if there is one. EK
    kinesisProducer.foreach { kinesisProducerRef =>
      if (sender.equals(kinesisProducerRef)) {
        log.info(kinesisProducerRef.path.name + " Started")
        log.info("Starting " + restEndpointRef.path.name)
        IO(Http)(context.system) ! Http.Bind(restEndpointRef, "0.0.0.0", port = 8061)
      }
}
```

While this adds a little extra boilerplate, I don't think it's too bad. There are probably ways I could reduce the boilerplate more.

Typesafe also recommended I look at [Akka Extensions](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/extending-akka.html) and [ExtendedActorSystem](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/#akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem)

Answer (score 5):

Reflection does not help for things which are not in your `classpath`. Anything not in class path means `"Java does not know about the existence of this entity."`.

Now, when it comes to any instantiated actor ( It does not matter where... It can even even be in an alternative universe for all Akka cares about... ), you can refer to them via the `ActorRef` by using their `fully qualified` address ( path, umm.... alternate-universe... well... simple, ask your alternate-self :p ) example -

```
val as = ActorSystem( "myActorSystem" )

val refToRemoteActor: ActorSelection = as.actorSelection( "akka.tcp://my-sys@host.example.com:5678/user/service-b" )

// Now You can tell anything to your ActorSelction. But you can not ask them.

refToRemoteActor ! "my-message"
```

If you need `ActorRef` for your `remote Actor`, you need to send a message, such as the built-in `Identify` message, to the actor and use the `sender()` reference of a reply from that `remote Actor`.

Note : In case anyone is having problems getting Actors for alternate-universe, `Akka` does not provide Alternate-universe functionality yet. But, you can get it going, just if you can get a LAN-cable through that "quantum tunnel... or whatever the hell it is".

Comment: Actually you can just use the `resolveOne` method on `ActorSelection` to retrieve a `Future[ActorRef]` directly now.

Comment: @LMeyer Yup... but I think it does the same thing as sending an `Identify` message, and resolving the `ActorRef` from `sender`.

Comment: So I was not actually interested in remote actors at this point, I was really just concerned about how I could dynamically load an actor, like any other class, given it's name, i.e. "RestEnpoint"

Answer (score 0):

I would try and find another way to deal with your circular dependency issues as instantiating actors via reflection can get you into trouble, but it is possible as the code below shows:

```
package code

import akka.actor._
import scala.util._

object Test extends App{

  val system = ActorSystem("test")

  val shouldSucceed = tryAndInstantiate("code.MyTestActor")
  println(shouldSucceed)

  val shouldFail = tryAndInstantiate("code.FooTestActor")
  println(shouldFail )

  def tryAndInstantiate(name:String):Try[ActorRef] = {
    Try{
      val clazz = Class.forName(name)
      system.actorOf(Props(clazz))
    }
  }

}

class MyTestActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

If the class does not exist on the classpath, you will get a Failure.  You could also add additional logic to `tryAndInstantiate` to accommodate your need to check your config.